# Media player not stopping old song when new song is selected. Throws a null pointer exception also

Tags: android, media-player

Below code throws a null pointer exception at the "if" Condition.
I have a list of songs and on click on an item I want that song to be played and while clicking next item the previous song should stop playing and the newly selected song should get played. Could someone please help me???

```
MediaPlayer player = null;
    public void ringtonelistview() {
        final CharSequence[] ringtoneList = { "city_nights.mp3",
                "cute_morning_alarm.mp3", "melody_alarm_clock.mp3",
                "morning_alarm.mp3", "powiadomienie.mp3", "silver.mp3" };

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setTitle("Select one Ringtone");
        alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(ringtoneList, -1,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListe`enter code here`ner() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        final Uri myUri;
                        ringtoneName = (String) ringtoneList[item];
                        myUri = Uri.parse(getExternalFilesDir("").toString()
                                + "/RINGTONEFOLDER/" + ringtoneName);
                        try {
                            if (null != player || player.isPlaying() == true) {
                                player.stop();
                                player.release();
                            } else {
                                player = MediaPlayer.create(
                                        MainActivity.this,
                                        myUri);
                                player.start();
                                player = null;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
if(mediaplauer != null)
   if(mediaplayer.isplaying())
   {
     mediaplayer.stop();
     // start your new song
   }else{
     // start your new song
   }
```